# Possible to add a workflow on a website mailbox?

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-online, site-mailboxes

In SharePoint 2013 it is possible to create a website mailbox?

Is it possible to add a workflow onto it?

What I want is the following:

The Postbox got an E-Mail and at this time the workflow must add an Task in the Tasklist.

Is this in general possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alot of advantage / dis advantages of this.
 One of the draw back is.

- Emails are not getting into the SharePoint,Because they stored in the exchange. This means you can’t treat it as a SharePoint object and include it as part of a business process i.e workflow.

Alternate way is enable the incoming emails for document library.

Comment: Another disadvantage of SharePoint Online are that incoming emails are not possible.

Comment: right, but he did not mentioned SPO?

Comment: It's tagged SPO, so I assumed

Comment: yes i mean spo. anyway thank you for your response